# Van der Waals equation in PT coordinates

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, gas, phase-diagram

Can [Van der Waals equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) be meaningfully interpreted in PT plane? Are there modified versions of this equation, which would allow correctly reproducing the liquid-gas separation curve with a critical point? How should one interpret isochores hitting zero pressure at finite volume and temperature:
$$
P=\frac{nRT}{V-nb}-\frac{an^2}{V^2}
$$
(*Remark:* I suppose some of these difficulties can be resolved using [Maxwell construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_construction), rather than directly analyzing the VdW isochores.)

**Background:**
Typical phase diagram with a liquid-gas separation line and a critical point (see [Phase transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition)):
[image]

Comment: What do you mean "correctly reproducing the liquid-gas separation curve with a critical point"? The vdw equation *does* predict V/L equilibrium with a critical point, but its predictions are not accurate enough for engineering calculations. It is, nonetheless, qualitatively correct and it can be interpreted on any thermodynamic plane, although the $PV$ plain is simpler to discuss.

Comment: @Themis Indeed, WdV equation is usually discussed in PV-diagram, while liquid-gas transition is typically discussed in PT-diagram. I want to see discussion of WdV in PT plane. E.g., how should one interpret points with zero pressure (at finite V, T)? A reference to a reliable source would be enough for me personally, but the community could benefit from an expanded answer.

Comment: Actually, we discuss $V/L$ transitions on the $PV$ graph. Subcritical isotherms have a characteristic "loop"  which is unstable. When this loop is removed the isotherm has the proper form and shows the $V/L$ transition. Zero (or negative) pressure occur only inside the unstable portion. Cubic equations of state are discussed in chemical engineering thermodynamics. Here is one source: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fundamentals_of_Chemical_Engineering_The/gU1Mx5tQTAkC?hl=en (unfortunately limited preview). I can post an expanded answer if that's what you are looking for.